# VMWare Workstation Keyboard and Mouse stop working

Tags: virtual-machine, keyboard, mouse, vmware

I'm having a problem with vmware and keyboard/mouse detection and I'm hoping that you can help me.

I use an Oracle vm and sometimes (worryingly enough) I can't write with the keyboard or click with the mouse in the vm, although it was working until now.
I use my laptop with ***integrated keyboard and touchpad*** and outside the vm I have no problems.

At first I thought it was a freeze. So I allocated more **CPU** and **memory** but found that the vm wasn't spitting. When this happens when I'm in the middle of a sentence, I always see the pointer blinking.

I can also connect via ssh without any problems and when I use the top command, I don't detect any machine overload (cpu and memory 5%-20%).

The only ***"solution"*** that works is a **restart**, but it's not very viable to do it every time.

Do you know of a more suitable solution to my problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: VMware here for years. No issues with mouse or keyboard. Make sure VMware Tools have been properly installed in the Guest machine

Comment: @John I hadn't thought to look, thank you. However, I don't see any problems with it.

Comment: Make a new temporary machine and see if keyboard and mouse work. This will help you determine if the issue is VMware oriented or Virtual Machine guest oriented.

Comment: @John I'll give it a try. But on other vm's, I don't have any problems (I think). It's pretty much random, sometimes it's after several hours that it triggers, sometimes after 10 min. This is a vm I use mainly for java coding with netbeans. I've just had 4 hours without a hitch, and now it's gone again.

Comment: It seems like it is an oracle issue

Comment: Can you confirm that just the screen isn't freezing up? Try playing a video with audio in another window and see if that stops when the keyboard and mouse stop.

Comment: @User5910 I didn't try it with a video but I had the same problem with an Ubuntu vm yesterday while I was writing a python script and I saw the bar blinking and after 5 min the screen started to darken slowly until it went to sleep.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in v17.  I had no issues with v15, but now I occasionally lose my keyboard and mouse within the VM.  A reboot of the guest usually works, but it's very frustrating.
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VMWare-17-5-0-update-causes-workstation-keyboard-and-mouse/td-p/2995237

Comment: Same thing happens to me on ubuntu and rockylinux. As x4gl mentioned, it happens when i type fast. The machine doesn't actually freeze. You can still connect to it with ssh. Nothing i tried fixed it untill i rebooted the machine. I tried restarting gnome, display manager, etc. Nothing shows in journalctl. Running vmware player or Vmware workstation as administrator or not also doesn't help. Using enhanced keyboard also doesn't work. 17.5 is full of bugs, including vmnat which also ruins the cpu at some point.

Comment: Similar issues with two separate machines.  Found it to occur during fast typing and when copying text from the host OS.  The reports here all seem to suggest Linux as guest OS but don't mention host OS which may be a factor.  In my case Windows 11.

Answer (score 4):

This should be a VMware issue, not oracle. I had exactly the same problem as you in the last few days. The difference is that I am using arch and ubuntu VMs. So far I haven't found anything that would solve this problem. It seems that the problem occurs mostly when typing quickly or pasting from outside the VM.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I hadn't identified any particular cause but I'll try to be careful for the next times it happens.

Comment: As far as I'm currently using it, it seems that upgrading to version 17.5 is the reason to this problem.
I don't know which version you're using. If you're using version 17.5, trying a rollback to 17.0 or lowwer (uninstalling and reinstalling) may handle the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same issue on my laptop.
I'm using the built in keyboard and touch pad so not an issue with bluetooth or anything.

I'm running Kali in VMware Workstation 17 Player and my keyboard will stop working for no apparent reason (mouse sometimes will still work weirdly) I've had it happen while trying to copy over files from the host but I've also had it when changing tabs in a terminal.

In Kali, there is an activity graph in the top right that bounces up and down showing when this happens that the VM hasn't frozen or anything, it's still active, I simply cannot interact with it anymore.

Restarting doesn't even always fix it for me, sometimes I'll restart after the issue and in the grub menu the arrow keys will work but the moment it boots into the image the keyboard will no longer work.

I've tried reinstalling/updating VMtools, I've tried deleting the VM and reinstalling from a fresh ISO download and I've even tried reinstalling VMware itself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue on vmware workstation 17 player on a windows 11 host with an ubuntu 23.10 VM.

System work fine and stop capturing keybord and mouse after a while..
System still working and is fully operational and controllable with anydesk ..

The only solution i got is to restarting the VM!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that this issue is happening with me on both Ubuntu 23.10 and Fedora 38 guests.

I am using VMWare Workstation Pro 17.5.0 build-22583795 on Windows 11 Pro, 64-bit (Build 22621.2715) 10.0.22621.

The frustrating issue is that after a few hours, randomly, the guest VM will stop accepting mouse and keyboard input. However the guest is still "running" because I can see notifications and music in the background is still audible.

I have to stop the machine and restart in VMWare.

If I reboot from inside the VM the issue still persists.

I am using the distro included versions of open-vm-tools, which is the recommended solution when trying to install the tools manually.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I think i have a solution.

I edit the .vmx file and change the mouse integration setting by adding :

```
mks.gamingMouse.policy = "gaming"
```

Since yesterday i have no more problem but i need to ctrl+alt to exit MV window now.
I didn't try any other `mks.gamingMouse.policy` value for now.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround at vmware forum:

(1) Power off the VM, and add the config option:

```
keyboard.allowBothIRQs = FALSE
```

This might cause your Linux VM's input to hang if the Guest tries to Sleep/Hibernate, but it may work-around the problem.

Source:
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VMWare-17-5-0-update-causes-workstation-keyboard-and-mouse/m-p/2997783

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with VMWare Workstation PRO version 17.5 on Windows 11 with an Ubuntu host. It seems to be a [known bug](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VMWare-17-5-0-update-causes-workstation-keyboard-and-mouse/m-p/2997783) as pointed out by Chris Oversmith [here](https://superuser.com/a/1819131/145581). Following proposed solutions apparently causes other secondary effects like getting ghost key presses.

Reverted to version 17.0.2, so far so good, just remember it will re-ask you to enter your product key. In order to revert your VMWare Workstation version you only have to uninstall the current version and install the old one. Navigating to 17.0.2 requires you to log into your VMware account.